# Angular UI Bootstrap open modal within modal

Tags: angularjs

I am using Angular UI Bootstrap modal to open content within modal, and works fine. The problem is if I have a link within the modal content that should open another modal then it doesn't work.

How can I open unlimited numbers of modals within modals?

```
 $scope.showModal = function (modal_id, modal_size, modal_backdrop) {
        $rootScope.currentModal = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: modal_id,
            size: modal_size,
            backdrop: typeof modal_backdrop == 'undefined' ? true : modal_backdrop,
            scope: $scope
        });           
    };
```

then I can just do:

```
$scope.showModal('template', 'lg');
```

Comment: Why would you want to immediately open a modal within a modal? Before the first modal even got a chance to exist?

Comment: I think to open two modals is not good practice. For example Angular material doesn't support multiple modal structure and they are not going to change it. I would use `ng-show` / `ng-hide` of model content

Comment: So, imagine the following. You have a rest service that provides you the content for modal, right? When you show some content inside the modal, the content might have a link to another content, right? When clicking that link to show the content, of course you make a REST call, get the content and show it in the modal, same or new modal ... however in my case I can see the first but not the successive contents ...

Comment: Of course I have nothing against showing the content in the same modal